# How do I execute multiple test class parallely. which using same function in another class using testng

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, testng

How can I execute multiple test class `'test1'` and `'test2'` parallely? Which is using the same function in another class using TestNG.

When I define the parallel option as 'classes' and thread-count as '2' in TestNG XML, the login page is loading two times, but 'sendelement' method is executing in single browser two times simultaneously.

for eg; if my login is `'user1'`, `sendelement` function execute two times as `'user1user1'` in the username field and shows invalid login.

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--  <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd"> -->
<suite name="Suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="2">

    <test name="NavigationTest">
    <classes>
            <class name="Test1" />
            <class name="Test2" />
    </classes>
    </test>
</suite>

public class Test1 {

    loginToUserPage(strUserName, strPassword);
}

public class Test2{

    loginToUserPage(strUserName, strPassword);
}


public class Test3
{
    public void loginToUserPage(String strUserName,String strPassword) 
     {
        webdriverCommon.windowMaximise();
        webdriverCommon.sendElement(CommonRepo.userName_Edit, strUserName);
        webdriverCommon.sendElement(CommonRepo.password_Edit, strPassword);
        webdriverCommon.clickElement(CommonRepo.logginButton_buttton);

    }
}
```

Comment: Where do your username and password come from? I don't see that data anywhere.

Comment: strUserName,strPassword are username, password variables..                                      CommonRepo.userName_Edit and CommonRepo.userName_Edit are the By elements for input fields in UI

Comment: Can you show the actual test class where you pass the data?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using one webDriver, `webdriverCommon`. You'll need to setup your framework such that each class or test uses its own driver. I have a TestBase class that each test class inherits from. The following example is using JUnit but the idea is the same.

```
public class TestBase {

    protected WebDriver driver;
    protected String baseUrl = "http://example.com/";
    protected String hubUrl = "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub";

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception{
        try {
            DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(hubUrl), capability);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception{
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```